# Can my Macbook (Retina, 12-inch, 2017) output 4K resolution content to my TV/Monitor via a HDMI cable?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, resolution, 4k

I have a MacBook (Retina, 12-inch, 2017) and obviously my screen resolution is not 4K, but what I'd like to know is if that limits the ability to stream my screen at a higher resolution on a higher resolution (4k) screen. Is it possible for me to connect my MacBook to a 4K monitor and watch for example Netflix in 4K or will the monitor resolution always be limited by the maximum resolution of my MacBook?

I have seen some similar questions here but none of them have cleared up 100%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specification for your MacBook's capability with external displays is:

Up to 4096 by 2304 resolution at 60Hz.

(Taken from [everymac.com](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/specs/macbook-core-m3-1.2-12-mid-2017-specs.html))

So that is greater than 4K, which is 3840 x 2160.

Most modern Macs can output to external displays that are larger than the built-in display; and usually more than one! (But yours can only support one.)